# Trying to fetch points of interest using Overpass API but it throws an error

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm relatively new to Overpass and Uber H3. I'm trying to find all the points of interests associated with hexagons within New York City. I'm able to find and generate all the hexagons within New York City. The idea I had was to find all the PoI and then iterate through each and assign them to the correct hexagon. The following is the query I'm trying to use to fetch "buildings" in Python on Google Colab:

```
     [out:json];
      area["alt_name"="New York City"]->.searchArea;
      (
        node["building"](area.searchArea);
        way["building"](area.searchArea);
        rel["building"](area.searchArea);
      );
      out center;
    (._;>;);
    out;
```

For some reason, when I use buildings tag, it takes a very long time and eventually throws this error.

> IncompleteRead                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py in _read_chunked(self, amt)
> 591
> --> 592                 value.append(self._safe_read(chunk_left))
> 593                 if amt is not None:
>
> 5 frames IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(1686 bytes read, 2378 more
> expected)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> IncompleteRead                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py in _read_chunked(self, amt)
> 596             return b''.join(value)
> 597         except IncompleteRead:
> --> 598             raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
> 599
> 600     def _readinto_chunked(self, b):
>
> IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

If I use "tourism" and "historic" together its able to execute the query.
Is there any way to prevent this? Is it something wrong with my approach?

Comment: I believe the issue is due to the large volume of data being retrieved.

Comment: I need the data, is there some way to force it to give all of the data despite the volume? @Nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set a timeout value for your Overpass API request and it helps in handling requests that take too long. This code creates a JSON file as output of your Overpass query.

```
import requests
import json

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
area["alt_name"="New York City"]->.searchArea;
(
  node["building"](area.searchArea);
  way["building"](area.searchArea);
  rel["building"](area.searchArea);
);
out center;
(._;>;);
out;
"""

try:
    response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': overpass_query}, timeout=60)  # Set the timeout in seconds
    data = response.json()
    with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

    # Process the data as needed
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print("Request timed out.")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to convert this result a gdf (geodataframe)?

Comment: I believe you can. I am going to take a look